# Where to find or how to create from scratch a shapefile of an obscure city?

Tags: openstreetmap, data, mongolia

I am trying to find the shapefiles of a couple of cities in Mongolia, for example: Sukhbaatar (in Selenge, Mongolia).  I haven't been able to find a source that provides these shapefiles, so I thought maybe I could get the city shapefile from OSM.  Currently I try to export the osm file after typing in Sukhbaatar, Selenge, Mongolia and use osmtogeojson (https://tyrasd.github.io/osmtogeojson/) to get it into geojson form first. However, the features are an empty array.  Since that doesn't work, is there an alternative to obtain the shapefile or geojson of an obscure city?

Comment: I suspect that your question would be just as on-topic or more so at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange which has an [OpenStreetMap tag](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openstreetmap?sort=votes).

Answer (score 1):

You can download data of Mongolia from [geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/mongolia.html) server. The server has data extracts from OpenStreetMap and are updated regularly. It has also shapefile format as you can see in the common format available at the above link. However, I am not sure if the region you are interested in is available or not, but you can try and see.